# How to store long values in nsmutablearray in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to have a array which contains `long` value. this one contains `int`.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *selectedMessages;
```

adding element to it:

```
[selectedMessages addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:id]]
```

retrieving each element:

```
for (id selectedMessageId in self.selectedMessages) {
    // selectedMessageId is int
}
```

How should I change this to store long values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber` class has `numberWithLong` and `longValue` methods.

In your example `selectedMessageId` is not `int`. It is `NSNumber`. You can retrieve its `int` value by using `intValue` method. Therefore as you need `long` use methods that I've provided above

Comment: Don't forget you can simply do: `[selectedMessages addObject:@(anyNumericVariable)];`.